# Add parameters to MUI Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui, google-places-autocomplete

I am fairly new to React and have just started using the Google Maps Autocomplete API following the MUI example. I would like for the autocomplete to only serve geocoding results but cannot figure out where in my code to add parameters?

I've studied the Google Maps documentation (still a bit out of my depth if I'm honest) and understand how it works but not how to implement it.

Here is my code (exactly the same as the MUI example):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import LocationOnIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocationOn';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import parse from 'autosuggest-highlight/parse';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

function loadScript(src, position, id) {
  if (!position) {
    return;
  }

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('async', '');
  script.setAttribute('id', id);
  script.src = src;
  position.appendChild(script);
}

const autocompleteService = { current: null };

export default function GoogleMaps() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const loaded = React.useRef(false);

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !loaded.current) {
    if (!document.querySelector('#google-maps')) {
      loadScript(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places',
        document.querySelector('head'),
        'google-maps',
      );
    }

    loaded.current = true;
  }

  const fetch = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      throttle((request, callback) => {
        autocompleteService.current.getPlacePredictions(request, callback);
      }, 200),
    [],
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    if (!autocompleteService.current && window.google) {
      autocompleteService.current =
        new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    }
    if (!autocompleteService.current) {
      return undefined;
    }

    if (inputValue === '') {
      setOptions(value ? [value] : []);
      return undefined;
    }

    fetch({ input: inputValue }, (results) => {
      if (active) {
        let newOptions = [];

        if (value) {
          newOptions = [value];
        }

        if (results) {
          newOptions = [...newOptions, ...results];
        }

        setOptions(newOptions);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [value, inputValue, fetch]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="google-map-demo"
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.description
      }
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      options={options}
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      filterSelectedOptions
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setOptions(newValue ? [newValue, ...options] : options);
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Add a location" fullWidth />
      )}
      renderOption={(props, option) => {
        const matches = option.structured_formatting.main_text_matched_substrings;
        const parts = parse(
          option.structured_formatting.main_text,
          matches.map((match) => [match.offset, match.offset + match.length]),
        );

        return (
          <li {...props}>
            <Grid container alignItems="center">
              <Grid item>
                <Box
                  component={LocationOnIcon}
                  sx={{ color: 'text.secondary', mr: 2 }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs>
                {parts.map((part, index) => (
                  <span
                    key={index}
                    style={{
                      fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400,
                    }}
                  >
                    {part.text}
                  </span>
                ))}

                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  {option.structured_formatting.secondary_text}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </li>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can add componentRestrictions to the request object in the React useMemo hook before getPlacePredictions is called. For example use the snippet below in your code to limit results to Australia

```
const fetch = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      throttle((request, callback) => {
        request.componentRestrictions = {country: 'au'};
        autocompleteService.current.getPlacePredictions(request, callback);
      }, 200),
    [],
  );
```

More information about componentRestrictions can be found in the [Google Maps Platform docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction)

Comment: thanks for the help! I've looked into your solution and have played a bit with it but cannot seem to use it to only filter results based on their types through this solution. I need the autocomplete to only return geographic places (countries or cities), without offering companies, addresses, ...